# What is going wrong with ggts 3.6.3 on linux (e.g. broken code completion, compile errors)?

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite, ggts

I downloaded [GGTS 3.6.3](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.4/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz), extracted, and ran it on Ubuntu 14.10.

I tried importing an existing grails project and when that failed, I created a new workspace and a new grails project ("test"), inside of which I created a single controller ("test").

Basically nothing works. For example, when I try to write a simple line like `import java.util.HashSet`, the UI crashes to a halt and code completion fails with:
[image: Grooy Code Completions error]

Or when I type a line like `import java.util.HashSet` code manually (without code completion) I see various compile errors appear in eclipse's `stdout` like:

```
/test/grails-app/controllers/test/TestController.groovy: 3 Groovy:unable to resolve class java.util
/test/grails-app/controllers/test/TestController.groovy: 3 Groovy:Invalid import  @ line 3, column 8.
/test/grails-app/controllers/test/TestController.groovy: 3 Groovy:Invalid import  @ line 3, column 8.
/test/grails-app/controllers/test/TestController.groovy: 3 Groovy:unable to resolve class java.util
/test/grails-app/controllers/test/TestController.groovy: 3 Groovy:Invalid import  @ line 3, column 8.
/test/grails-app/controllers/test/TestController.groovy: 3 Groovy:Invalid import  @ line 3, column 8.
/test/grails-app/controllers/test/TestController.groovy: 3 Groovy:unable to resolve class java.util.Ha
/test/grails-app/controllers/test/TestController.groovy: 3 Groovy:Invalid import  @ line 3, column 8.
/test/grails-app/controllers/test/TestController.groovy: 3 Groovy:Invalid import  @ line 3, column 8.
```

But while the error appears in an individual file in eclipse:
[image]

... there's no summary view showing me all of the errors. That is, eclipse's "Problems" tab is blank:

[image]

In short, I can't accomplish even the simplest tasks in a fresh project, let alone actually opening my existing project. Is anyone else experiencing these issues?

Comment: You say this is in a fresh project? So I imagine it should be relatively easy to create a bug report that includes a set of reproducible steps. Could you raise a bug report here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE

Comment: ACtually, the errors look similar to those in this bug report: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3994 although that was a problem specifically involving traits. Still it may be worth trying updating greclipse from nightly build (that bug was only fixed yesterday). FYI: the fix is not yet on the update site, it will be once there's been a successful build here: https://build.spring.io/browse/GRECLIPSE-E44TP

Comment: @Kris I'd love to, but http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE doesn't appear to support new user registration (or I just can't figure out where/how to register. The message says "To request an account, please contact your JIRA administrators.", but I don't know how to act on that advice.)

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one (https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/HAUS-2323). That message is confusing indeed. It looks like you have to signup here: https://xircles.codehaus.org/signup